# What is our stance on questions about board & card game-related events?

Tags: discussion

What is our policy on questions about board & card game-related events that do not directly involve how to play the games? For instance, could someone ask about how a Magic tournament is run, or a convention? I could imagine several sorts of questions in this vein:

- How do I find out about official Magic tournaments in my area?
- How do I make sure that people don't walk off with games in an "opening gaming" room at a convention?
- How can I find board gamers in the city I just moved to?
- What do I need to do to qualify for the North American Bridge Championships?
- Does GenCon have designated areas for playing board games?

This question was inspired by  [When is International TableTop Day?](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/q/29782/3389), which currently has a vote to close "because it is about the schedule of an event, not about board or card games". While I realize it's not an ideal question because it is time-sensitive, I would like to know more about the general policy we have about gaming-related events.

Note that we do have [tournament](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/tournament), but I don't think we have anything about non-tournament events, aside from the newly created [events](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/events).

Comment: Old answer says thumbs up - http://meta.boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/61/are-questions-about-boardgames-related-events-on-topic

Comment: While I disagree with the reason to close on your question, I don't think it is a particularly good question. For one if you search for "International Tabletop Day" 4 of the top 5 results (at least for me) had the date, most of them in great big letters. Also unlike the rest of your example questions your actual question's answer becomes outdated without constant updates to the answer

Comment: A better way to advertise for Tabletop Day might've been to ask *what* it is. The schedule could still be mentioned as part of an answer, but I suspect that giving an overview of the event and why it's awesome would be more helpful anyways!

Comment: @Jefromi Actually, the intention wasn't to advertise, but merely to answer a legitimate question. It's been done in my area several times and people in my group have asked when it is.

Comment: @Thunderforge Ah. I figured it was more about spreading the news since as diego pointed out it's pretty trivial to find out when it is, easier than posting a question. (And anyone else looking would presumably use Google and find the answer and never see the question either.)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes these sorts of questions are on-topic. While they are not about board game rules, they are still questions that have to do with board games and are best answered by board game experts.

Answer (score 1):

For what it's worth I vote we keep them. I don't think a question about a meetup is necessarily off topic. I do think it will open the door to many different types of off topic questions like "Where's the best board game store in [Location]" or "How much should I sell [Game] for?" but questions like "When is Tabletop Day?" i think are fine because it has a definitive answer because of the implied time restriction.